# MobilePush getting lat/long from user

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, geolocation, mobilepush-ios, push

so for iOS MobilePush, i have location based and outbound based push notifications working, and configured the following

```
ETPush pushManager
```

with proper services enabled, and other changes I need to make to the app completed (such as sending update in the background even if app is not in foreground etc)

Is there a way for me to get the lat long of each device who subscribed to the location based? if so where?
if not, do i have to manually attach the lat long as attributes and send them from app to salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to get the coordinate of the device in the Marketing Cloud system unless you were to do as you are suggesting - send lat/lon back into the system as an attribute or some other back-end hook (Marketing Cloud never stores device location on the server).

As a customer, you'd be on the hook to set data as you mention and leverage that in your segmentation audience.

You would want to make every effort to **not** persist *specific* user location without their knowledge nor without a way for them to remove that data - there are privacy implications which should be taken into account.

Additionally, you should work to limit updates to MobilePush registration data to be a good SDK/MobilePush data/network citizen (i.e. don't push very small changes in location back into the system over and over).